# Auto Layout Constraint Lifecycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to get a handle on the best way to apply Auto Layout constraints in code instead of IB.

I need the topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide property of my ViewController and the developer docs say to query for it in the viewDidLayoutSubviews selector. In the other ViewController lifecycle methods the top and bottom layout guides haven't been set yet.

My question is that since this can be called numerous times it feels bad to do this in viewDidLayoutSubviews multiple times:

1. Remove prior constraints in the view.
2. Set up the constraints again.
3. Call [self.view layoutSubviews] to apply them again.

Is there a better place to do this? For instance where I know a selector will only be called once and I apply my constraints. If any keyboard actions are called I can update them appropriately instead of destroying the others and rebuilding from scratch.

Comment: I solved this problem for me by adding a boolean property to my VC, starting it as NO, only update constraints if value is NO, then at the end of viewDidLayoutSubviews is called, set the property to YES. Then if you need to update the constraints again on a specific action, like keyboard opening, just set the boolean back to NO.